# Android EditText view Floating Hint set enabled true when changing the focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design

I have 2 EditText that are separated by a textview ,
using floating labels animation,
The edit 1 is the first to have focus . When the user selects the edit 2 they change the focus of the first .

Follows the example code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textFilter|textCapCharacters"
        android:digits="@string/filterCharacter"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextGray"
        android:hint="@string/hintPlaca"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textFilter|number"
        android:digits="@string/filterNumber"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextGray"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I want the first EditText remain activated when the user changes the focus to the second. Can anyone give me a hint of how to do this ?

Comment: Yes . I want the first EditText be activated with the effect of TextInputLayout when the user clicks the second EditText.